# Lagging response from homerow movement keys in visual mode

Tags: vim

When I use the hjkl movement keys (hnei for me, as I've mapped these keys to work with the colemak layout) in normal mode, they move perfectly fine without any noticeable delay.  However, in visual mode, the key corresponding to moving right ("i" for me), causes a really annoying lag.  I have a feeling that one of the plugins I installed may have mapped a command to be a combination of "i" and another key, but I can't find it anywhere.  Why is this lag happening?  More specifically, am I missing something in my vimrc or plugins that may be conflicting with my movement mappings?

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

Plugin 'gmarik/vundle'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
Plugin 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
Plugin 'kchmck/vim-coffee-script'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-repeat'
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'tomtom/tcomment_vim'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plugin 'tomasr/molokai'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
Plugin 'kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim'
Plugin 'docunext/closetag.vim'
Plugin 'mattn/emmet-vim'

" HNEI arrows. Swap 'gn'/'ge' and 'n'/'e'.
noremap n gj|noremap e gk|noremap i l|noremap gn j|noremap ge k
nnoremap <silent> jj :noh<CR>
let g:mapleader=","
noremap <space> i
" Last search.
nnoremap k n
nnoremap K N
" BOL/EOL/Join Lines.
noremap l ^|noremap L $|noremap <C-l> J
" _r_ = inneR text objects.
onoremap r i
" Switch tabs.
nnoremap <C-i> <C-PageDown>|nnoremap <C-h> <C-PageUp>
" SwiS1S1tch panes.
noremap H <C-w>h|noremap I <C-w>l|noremap N <C-w>j|noremap E <C-w>k
" Scroll up/down.
noremap = <C-y>|noremap - <C-e>
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap : ;
inoremap jj <Esc>
noremap U <C-r>
nnoremap + <C-a>|nnoremap - <C-x>
noremap ' `|noremap ` '
vnoremap s S
nnoremap <CR> o<Esc>
noremap _ <c-_><c-_>
vnoremap <Leader>a :Tabularize /:<CR>
" Vim Display.
set t_Co=256                     
set shortmess+=I
set display+=lastline
set showtabline=1
set backspace=2
set textwidth=0
" Text Display.
syntax on
set number
set guicursor+=a:blinkon0
set hlsearch
set wrap
set lbr
set showbreak=···\
" Two-space tabs.
set expandtab
set smarttab
" Editing.
set autoindent
set whichwrap+=<,>,h,l,b,s,[,]
set splitbelow|set splitright
" Searching and matching.
set incsearch
set ignorecase|set smartcase
set gdefault
set showmatch
" System.
filetype plugin indent on
set mouse=a
set t_RV=1
set history=1000
set wildmenu
set wildmode=longest,full
au BufEnter * set ignorecase
set nohidden
set laststatus=2
let g:EasyMotion_do_mapping = 0
nmap f <Plug>(easymotion-s)
let g:EasyMotion_smartcase = 1
nnoremap <silent> <Leader><Leader> :NERDTreeTabsToggle<CR>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:verbose vmap i
```

will tell you all visual mode mappings starting with `i` (and where it got defined, so you can identify the plugin). As most "inner" text objects start with `i` and are also available in visual mode, this conflict is indeed likely.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I was able to fix the issue.  You were right about "i" being the inner text object modifier, but the `:verbose vmap i` is a useful command!